# Calculating Column Similarity in Spark Mapping Function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm pretty new to spark, and I'm currently trying to calculate the column similarity of a field (represented as a 2-D array) for each column in my rdd (inspired by this link - https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html)

For example if my data looked like this

[image]
I want my final map to look like this

[image]
My mapper function looks like this

```
def mapper(pairs):
  id = pairs[0]
  matrix = pairs[1]

  rows = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(matrix)
  mat = RowMatrix(rows)
  score = mat.columnSimilarities().entries.first().value
  return (id,score)
```

The problem is when I try to map my rdd to become a row matrix, I get this error

> pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

From what I understand we are not able to run an rdd in a map function. I have tested this with the spark context outside the mapper on some examples and I can get that to work. so my question is #1) why can't we? #2) what are ways we can get column similarity without using a row matrix? #3) Perhaps I'm missing configuration somewhere or missing lines in my mapper function

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) why can't we?

Because nesting distributed contexts is not allowed. All the details can be found in SPARK-5063, which is already mentioned in the exception message.

> 2) what are ways we can get column similarity without using a row matrix?

Use your favorite local stack (NumPy / SciPy stack comes to mind).

> 3) Perhaps I'm missing configuration somewhere or missing lines in my mapper function

You don't.

Comment: i was so heck bent trying to get it to work with row matrix (or implementing myself), never thought of just using another stack. thanks for the insight!